# Is there a way to add variables into strings from string.properties file?

Tags: java, spring, kotlin

I was told to store all strings needed for the applications in the .properties (so that future app localizations are easier to maintain) file which I did
Now I have to alter some of them so they contain some variables inside of them
for example
string "hey, you have a new message" should now be "hey, , you have a new message from " and the string should still be stored in the .properties file

What I have now:

- notifications.properties file with strings stored like
  fcm.msg.new-message-body = "Hey, you have a new message"
- Config class that initializes said strings so I can use them

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "fcm.msg")
@PropertySource("classpath:notification.properties")
class FCMConfig {
    lateinit var newMessageBody: String
```

Comment: You try `strings.xml` which will provide you localizations and it is much easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

here is the way-

store string data in a properties file

```
new-message-body = "Hey, you have a new message"
```

then where you want to use that string then just use this

```
@Value("${new-message-body}")
 private String message;
```

Then you can use the message variable anywhere in that class.

if you want do not want to create any variable then just

```
System.out.println(@Value("${new-message-body}"));
```

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin u can do it like

```
var variable_name:String=getString(R.string.newMessageBody)
```